# Galois Cohomology and $\sqrt{k} \notin \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

I know it seems excessive, but I have been trying to understand the relationship between two concepts:

- Galois cohomology
- Fermat Descent

The first one is very abstract and I know very little about it.  Many sources indicate there should be some kind of relationship e.g. Wikipedia

> In this way, abstractly-defined cohomology groups in the theory become identified with descents in the tradition of Fermat.

and I can go find real math textbooks that indicate the same, but none of them really indicate how cohomology was (implicitly used).  The same Wikipedia article on [**descent**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent) cites two examples:

- $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}$
- $p = a^2 + b^2$ iff $p = 4k+1$

There's lots of discussion and staring at the result I can see "cohomological" things about them, but none of the discussions really link the abstract and concrete discussions.

I have seen [Skorobogatov's](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/torsors-and-rational-points/76C9B8890C39601665082CFA8258E20E) book still doesn't show me how to approach this specific case.

---

Attaching names to all the concepts, we are looking for points in $X = \{ x^2 - 2y^2 = 0 \} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}^2 $.  I could think of several approaches:

**#1** $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{R}$, I forget if $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}_2$, but certainly $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}_3, \mathbb{Q}_5$.  Therefore $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}$ by Hasse principle.

In other words, $X(\mathbb{A}) \neq \varnothing$ but $X(\mathbb{Q}_5) = \varnothing$ so that $X(\mathbb{A}) = \varnothing$. This is cheating, but we can see that an $H^1$ was involved.

**#2** There is a map $X(\mathbb{Z}) \stackrel{\div2}{\to} X(\mathbb{Z})$ by $(x,y) \to (y/2, x)$.  Once can produce an $\mathbb{R}$-valued invariant (such as a **height**) that decreases indefinitely.

---

In all these examples I don't know what $H^1$ is being used?  Perhaps there is a torsor $T$ and a field $\mathbb{Q}$ and we are computing $H^1( \mathbb{Q}, T)$ ?

I have been reading about **strong approximation** in it's various formulations.

$$ X(\mathbb{Q}) \to X(\mathbb{A}) \text{ is dense} $$

For my soft-ball examples, the use of cohomology should be very minimal, but I am failing to see the connection at all.

Comment: There is an excellent book on Galois cohomology by Serre.

Comment: Certainly $\sqrt2 \not\in \mathbb Q_2$, because $\mathrm{ord}_2(2) = 1$ and $\mathrm{ord}$ is $\mathbb Z$-valued on $\mathbb Q_2$.  I'm not sure if it's what you have in mind, but there is an identification $\mathbb Q^\times/(\mathbb Q^\times)^2 \cong \mathrm H^1(\mathbb Q, \mu_2)$ sending $k \mapsto (\sigma \mapsto (\sigma - 1)\sqrt k)$, that is, sending a square class to the coboundary in $\mathrm GL_1$ corresponding to either square root, which is necessarily $\mu_2$-valued.

Comment: supplement: [**28** proofs of the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/sq_root.shtml)